# How to prevent the client IP adress from being written to nginx error log

Tags: nginx, logging, gdpr

I can use `log_format` to remove the client IP from being written to the nginx access log. However, the error log always seems to include the client IP:

> 2018/05/18 15:43:55 [crit] 1234#1234: *1014 stat()
>   "/var/www/initech/widgets.js" failed (13: Permission denied),
>   **client: 203.0.113.74**, server: example.org, request: "GET /widgets.js HTTP/1.1", host: "example.org"

For GDPR compliance reasons I would like to stop the client IP from appearing in the error log. I know I can disable the error log entirely, but I don't want to do that. I want to fix the errors, not ignore them.

Comment: nginx supports [custom log formats via the `log_format` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#log_format), but the general understanding I have of the GDPR and error logging is that it's *generally* acceptable to collect IPs in error logs as long as there's log rotation and appropriate procedures/policies in place. See https://www.gdpreu.org/the-regulation/key-concepts/legitimate-interest/

Comment: There are quite a few situations in which the IP address in the error log is necessary.  And it is not mandatory to remove it.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246756/is-it-possible-to-specify-custom-error-log-format-in-nginx).